# Override host - ClientHttpRequestInterceptor ( Spring RestTemplate)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I m trying to override the 'host' through ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.
When i debug request.getHeaders().get("host") line, i m able to the uri which i changed properly. (www.test.com).

But when I try to retrieve the host header in spring controller for GET /product mapping, i m getting null value. could you please suggest why i get null value eventhough request header had 'host' value before hit GET /product.

I m using **resttemplate.getForObject(uri,ProductWrapper.class);**

**BeanFactoryIncerceptor.java**:

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ClientHttpRequestInterceptor hostHeaderInterceptor = (request, body, execution) -> {
            request.getHeaders().set("Accept", "application/json");

            if(request.getURI().getPath().endsWith("/product")) {
                request.getHeaders().set("host", "www.test.com");
            }
            ClientHttpResponse response= execution.execute(request, body);
            log.info("request header host:", request.getHeaders().get("host"));
            return response;
        };

        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Lists.newArrayList(hostHeaderInterceptor));

        return restTemplate;
```

**ProductController.java:**

```
 @GET
        @Path(value = "/product")
        public void getProducts(@RequestHeader(value="host") String headerHost,@RequestHeader(value="Accept") String accept)
```

//headerHost is null here.
//accept is null here

**Update 1:**

```
@ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true )@HeaderParam("Accept") String accept,@ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true )@HeaderParam("host") String headerHost
```

Now i'm getting value if i use @HeaderParam. But I'm expecting headerHost should be www.test.com which i was set through BeanFactoryInterceptor.java, but, i m getting real uri(www.google.com)

```
accept = application/json
headerHost = www.google.com
```

Why www.test.com didnt come to controller? Please suggest with your inputs.

**Update 2:**

After debuggging HttpUrlConnection.class which is used by spring RestTemplate internally, I understood sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders is false.

```
 allowRestrictedHeaders = ((Boolean)AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetBooleanAction("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders"))).booleanValue();
```

**Clarification required for below points**:
In intellij if i create Run configuration as 'Application' and pass the 'VM Options' as -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true, host is getting updated properly with www.test.com.

I'm using spring boot along with gradle for this application. It's one of the application which will be deployed along with other application in the application server.

What would be the best approach to pass -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true only for single application when it starts from the server? I dont have idea about deployment side. Please help with your inputs as i want to understand.

Comment: I suppose you know how request and response works. Browser and server side code in meaningful way. Browsers send their requests to the server with the actual host part then referer, method, encoding type and etc. Thats the standard every server side application has to follow. We cant do like the client(browser) sending the host as abc.com and then we can manipulate it to by doing something when reaches the server side code. against standard. You are actually talking about changing the http request , sitting on the server side. Think about it and the www standards.

Comment: @Vaibs. I agree with you. we have some legacy code in the application which we couldn't the change the architecture to achieve some requirement. finally we decided that go and change the host in the response.

Comment: @vaibs. If i add sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true in JVM_OPTS in websphere server, Will all applications which is hosted on wepsphere server will have sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true? Is it possible to configure sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true for one application and sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=false for all other application in wepshere server?

Comment: I wanted to post it as a solution but i will comment that we can spoof or fool the browser and the users uses browsers only in any way, desktop/mobile/mobile internally using android chrome or iPhone using Safari internally in their applications.

Comment: Actually, the application where we change host from server side, will be maintained and accessed only by back office admin team. This application  cant be accessed by end users.

Comment: Why you want to change host in your application , knowing it will never be integrated with your legacy application? I didnt get the point of manipulating the host.